# How to remove time information from date in this json structure?

Tags: php, json, date, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using cakephp v3.

I have a simple Model function;

```
public function getXXXoutput($xxx_term, $start_date, $end_date)    
{           
    $monthly_XXX_curves = TableRegistry::get('MonthlyXXXCurves');        
    $query = $monthly_XXX_curves
            ->find()                        
            ->select( ['date_transacted', 'output'] ) 
            ->toArray();

    return $query;        
}
```

The controller function looks like this;

```
public function apiGetXXX()
{
    $json_output = $this->MonthlyXXXCurves->getXXXoutput($xxx_term, $start_date, $end_date);
    echo json_encode($json_output);
}
```

The json format the controller returns looks like this;

```
[
{
output: 1.37,
date_transacted: "2015-01-01T00:00:00+0000"
},
{
output: 1.62,
date_transacted: "2015-02-01T00:00:00+0000"
}
]
```

I would like to remove the time information from `date_transacted` such that the final json structure would look like this;

```
[
{
output: 1.37,
date_transacted: "2015-01-01"
},
{
output: 1.62,
date_transacted: "2015-02-01"
}
]
```

How to modify the controller function to achieve the desired json structure?

Comment: you want to do it while fetching from database??

Comment: @ Niranjan N Raju, no preference as long as I get the desired json structure

Comment: What format are `$start_date` and `$end_date`?

Comment: #Peter, they are in string format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select date_transacted and format as DATE in your query

```
public function getXXXoutput($xxx_term, $start_date, $end_date)    
{           
    $monthly_XXX_curves = TableRegistry::get('MonthlyXXXCurves');        
    $query = $monthly_XXX_curves
            ->find()                        
            ->select(['transacted' => 'DATE(date_transacted)', 'output']) 
            ->toArray();

    return $query;        
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it does not work. There is a syntax error "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: "

Comment: Read how to use SQL functions http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions

Comment: @Salines You pass `fields' to `select`, not date object.

Comment: In Book you have example how to format date http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#aggregates-group-and-having

Comment: Selected your answer as the right answer since it is the Cakephp way. Thanks!

Comment: One thing I do not understand. `->select(['date_transacted' => 'DATE(date_transacted)', 'output']) ` does not work. However, your code `->select(['transacted' => 'DATE(date_transacted)', 'output']) ` works fine. Why can't `'date_transacted'` be used?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with CakePHP and so do not know how this is all processed. What I do know is that `$json_output` is an array and as such can be looped and modified.

```
foreach ($json_output as $key => $value) {
    $date = new DateTime($json_output[$key]['date_transacted']);
    $json_output[$key]['date_transacted'] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Add the above just before:

```
echo json_encode($json_output);
```

Comment: It works after making one minor modification. Change `DateTime` to '\DateTime' due to namespace issue in cakephp.

Comment: One thing I don't understand. Why do you need $value when it is not used?

Comment: @user768421 I can't use the key if I don't use the value as well. And I could use `$value['date_transacted']`. There is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

When you fetch records with `ORM` it bring back `date and time fields` as `Cake\I18n\Time` objects which is extended from `Carbon` and `Carbon` is extended from `DateTime`. You can just call `i18nFormat` or `format` method.

> Under the hood, CakePHP uses Carbon to power its Time utility. Anything you can do with Carbon and DateTime, you can do with Time.
>   For details on Carbon please see [their documentation](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).

[CakePHP - Time](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html)

```
$date_transacted->format('Y-m-d');
```